# Android Spannable text encoding after Html.tohtml()

Tags: android, encoding, utf-8, spannablestring, spannable

I am developing an application that uses Spannable text from EditText. After using Html.toHtml() method for Spannable text it gives me this kind of String on the exit.

```
&#1055;&#1086;&#1076;&#1072;&#1088;&#1086;&#1082; &#1082;&#1086; &#1076;&#1085;&#1102; &#1089;&#1074;&#1103;&#1090;&#1086;&#1075;&#1086; &#1042;&#1072;&#1083;&#1077;&#1085;&#1090;&#1080;&#1085;&#1072; &#1079;&#1072; 4 &#1085;&#1086;&#1095;&#1080; &#1080; 1 &#1076;&#1077;&#1085;&#1100; / &#1061;&#1072;&#1073;&#1088;&#1072;&#1093;&#1072;&#1073;&#1088; content: &#1055;&#1072;&#1088;&#1091; &#1085;&#1077;&#1076;&#1077;&#1083;&#1100; &#1085;&#1072;&#1079;&#1072;&#1076;, &#1103; &#1088;&#1077;&#1096;&#1080;&#1083; &#1087;&#1086;&#1076;&#1072;&#1088;&#1080;&#1090;&#1100; &#1089;&#1074;&#1086;&#1077;&#1081; &#1083;&#1102;&#1073;&#1080;&#1084;&#1086;&#1081; &#1085;&#1072; &#1076;&#1077;&#1085;&#1100; &#1089;&#1074;&#1103;&#1090;&#1086;&#1075;&#1086; &#1042;&#1072;&#1083;&#1077;&#1085;&#1090;&#1080;&#1085;&#1072; &#1087;&#1086;&#1076;&#1072;&#1088;&#1086;&#1082;, &#1080;&#1079;&#1075;&#1086;&#1090;&#1086;&#1074;&#1083;&#1077;&#1085;&#1085;&#1099;&#1081; &#1089;&#1074;&#1086;&#1080;&#1084;&#1080; &#1088;&#1091;&#1082;&#1072;&#1084;&#1080;. &#1053;&#1072;&#1081;&#1076;&#1077;&#1085;&#1085;&#1099;&#1077; &#1074; &#1080;&#1085;&#1090;&#1077;&#1088;&#1085;&#1077;&#1090;&#1077; &#1089;&#1072;&#1084;&#1086;&#1076;&#1077;&#1083;&#1082;&#1080; &#1084;&#1085;&#1077; &#1085;&#1077; &#1087;&#1086;&#1085;&#1088;&#1072;&#1074;&#1080;&#1083;&#1080;&#1089;&#1100;, &#1093;&#1086;&#1090;&#1077;&#1083;&#1086;&#1089;&#1100; &#1089;&#1076;&#1077;&#1083;&#1072;&#1090;&#1100; &#1095;&#1090;&#1086;-&#1090;&#1086;... annotation: &#8220; add your comment here &#8220;
```

when original text was this:

```
Пару недель назад, я решил подарить своей любимой на день святого Валентина подарок, изготовленный своими руками. Найденные в интернете самоделки мне не понравились, хотелось сделать что-то...
```

This is the code that i use

```
contentView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.contentPreview);
SpannableString contentText = (SpannableString) contentView.getText();
Log.e("Content Text",Html.toHtml(contentText));
```

Contentviews's code

```
<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/contentPreview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Content"
                    android:bufferType="spannable"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

My question is how can i normalize text i got from the TextView?

Thanks,
Arshak

Comment: normalize? it means ?

Comment: @pskink by saying "Normalize" i mean change text encoding to the normal one (Without "&#" symbols)

Comment: sorry, still have no idea what you want to do...

Comment: @pskink i want to change Spannable text encoding that i got from the textview so it could look like the "Original".

Comment: and why do you use toHtml ?

Comment: @pskink i use Html class because TextView can contain HTML tags in it (<b></b>) because i parse html content from the web page and Add it on the TextView.

Comment: @pskink I've found the solution, check my answer for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Looks like this was HTML Entity encoding, so for decoding you must Use Apache StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4() method.

```
TextView contentView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.contentPreview);
SpannableString contentText = (SpannableString) contentView.getText();
String htmlEncodedString = Html.toHtml(contentText);
String decodedString = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(htmlEncodedString);

Log.e("Content Text",decodedString);
```